# The Stable Marriage Problem

Tags: graph-theory

I'm studying graph theory and come across this Marriage Problem that could be solved by bipartite graph

Here is one conclusion from The Stable Marriage Problem

The Stable Marriage Problem marries every man to his optimal spouse.

Here is one way to prove

If a man M is married to a girl G on the final day , then everyone above
G on M preference list was crossed off, all these crossed
off women were infeasible for M. So G is M highest ranked feasible
spouse, that is his optimal spouse

I not really buy that reasoning so I try to prove by contradiction that lead to something like rogue couple.That is couple prefers each other to  their spouses

But here i'm stuck

Can somesome give me a direction to how to prove this by contradiction

NOTE:I want to make the term "optimal spouse" clear :  A person’s optimal spouse is their most pre-
ferred person if there is a stable matching in which the two people are married

Comment: @bof I have edited it .Thank for your comment

Answer (score 1):

I learned two-sided matching theory from econ classes, and here are some elementary ideas:

First, the property that every man marries his optimal spouse comes from the structure of the Gale-Shapley Algorithm, where men can choose whom to propose but women can only retain or reject men who propose to them. If you switch the role played by men and women the conclusion is also reversed. And if you find stable matching by methods other than the GS, this property might not hold either, since the stable matching may not be unique. In another word, in GS, man gets the best results among all stable matchings.

The intuition is straightforward and you already knew it. Now, prove it by contradiction. Here I translate a proof from Chinese: http://blog.csdn.net/u014309087/article/details/49098113

Consider a stable matching with GS, denoted by $\mu^*$, where a man $m$ prefer woman $W$ than his current spouse. Then he must be rejected by $W$, and wlog, suppose he is the first one in the group being rejected. So there must be another man $M$ proposed to $W$ and $W$ prefers $M$ than $m$: $M\succ_{W}m$

Next, consider a stable matching generated by other methods, denoted by $\mu$, where $m$ is married to $W$ and $M$ to $w$. In GS algorithm, we set $m$ is the first one being rejected, so $M$ has not been rejected by anyone before proposing to $W$. Since man proposes to women in descending order in GS, we can conclude that $W\succ_{M}w$.

Now, in $\mu$, $W$ prefers $M$ but is matched to $m$; $M$ prefers $W$ but is matched to $w$. Then $\mu$ would be blocked by the couple of $W$ and $M$ hence not stable, a contradiction.

To see why it is without loss of generality to assume $m$ is the first one in the group being rejected, notice that all we want from this assumption is to derive $W\succ_{M}w$. If it is true, we are done. If not, then $w\succ_{M}W$. But $M$ proposes to $W$ in GS, which means he already proposed to $w$ and was rejected. Then there must be another man $\mathbb M$ who proposed to $m$ and $\mathbb M\succ_{w}M$. Now change the notion of $(M, \mathbb M)$ to $(m, M)$ and proceed recursively, we see that our assumption is innocuous.